# Gitlab commit messages

Tags: gitlab, mantis

We're using Gitlab for source control, and MantisBT for issue tracking (boss's orders!)

Now we want to implement some kind of regex in the Gitlab commit messages, when a commit contains 'Mantis#1' that it automaticly generates a URL to http://mantis.local/view.php?id=1

Is this possible in Gitlab, (without having to write in Ruby?), and if so, how ?

Comment: You probably mean Gitlab, not Github, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible without writing code. As variant you can try change config file:

[Here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/helpers/issues_helper.rb#L40-L51) described logic for Internal issue trackers. [Here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L80-L106) described rules for internal issue trackers. You can try configure your own tracker support.

As example (I don't know which urls in your issue tracker)

```
issues_tracker:
  mantisbt:
    title: "MantisBT"
    project_url: "http://mantis.local/projects/:issues_tracker_id"
    issues_url: "http://mantis.local/view.php?id=:id"
    new_issue_url: "http://mantis.local/projects/:issues_tracker_id/issues/new"
```